Applying reinforced-learning on combination of continuous and discrete action space environment
I have a custom gym environment, where it has 3 continuous and 1 discrete action space. I would like to apply a reinforcement-learning algorithm, however I am not sure what to use.
Below you can find the environment code, action space is basically setting some parameters within the gas network which is called via self.func and observation space is the pressure results of nodes, and velocity results of elements:
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
import simtools as st


class GasNetworkEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, map_, qcorr_bounds, pset_bounds, cs_ctrl_bounds,
                 obs_size, func, func_args):
        super(GasNetworkEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Dict({
            'qcorr': gym.spaces.Box(
                low=np.array([qcorr_bounds[0]]),
                high=np.array([qcorr_bounds[1]]),
                dtype=np.float64),
            'pset': gym.spaces.Box(
                low=np.array([pset_bounds[0]]),
                high=np.array([pset_bounds[1]]),
                dtype=np.float64),
            'cs_ctrl': gym.spaces.Box(
                low=np.repeat(cs_ctrl_bounds[0], len(map_)),
                high=np.repeat(cs_ctrl_bounds[1], len(map_)),
                dtype=np.float64),
            'cs_state': gym.spaces.MultiBinary(
                sum([len(map_[k].no) for k in map_]))})
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(
            low=-1e5, high=1e5, shape=(obs_size,), dtype=np.float64)
        self.func = func
        self.func_args = func_args

    def step(self, action):  
        # call objective function (we are trying to minimize score which is bad when higher)
        node_results, element_results, score = self.func(action, self.func_args)
        reward = -score
   
        # observation
        observation = np.concatenate((node_results, element_results))

        # termination conditions (currently: no termination)
        done = False

        return observation, reward, done, {}

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        super().reset(seed=kwargs.get('seed', None))

        initial_observation = np.random.uniform(
            low=self.observation_space.low,
            high=self.observation_space.high,
            size=self.observation_space.shape)

        return initial_observation


What happens if you choose one randomly out of the algorithms you know?

@mkrieger1 I tried to implement a DQNAgent via Keras. The problem is, I cannot really test it so easily since self.func takes approximately 2 seconds to calculate and cannot be calculated parallel... If you could also help me test via an example function which is fast, I can also accept that answer!

Why can't you test it if self.func takes 2 seconds? How many seconds would it need to take so you could test it?

I though, I need to run it for really long to see if it is converging somewhere. @mkrieger1, at the moment all I see is total_reward being similar levels of negative number.
